# Elasticsearch date range returns no hits

Tags: python, datetime, elasticsearch

I'm quite confident I'm making some sort of mistake and it probably has to do with the way I'm mapping and/or storing my date field but I can't seem to figure out what is going wrong. I'm hoping someone here is able to give me some guidance.

I wrote a simple test applications to show you my problem:

```
from datetime import datetime
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

INDEX_NAME = "datetime-test"

ESCONN = Elasticsearch()
ESCONN.indices.create(index=INDEX_NAME, ignore=400)

obj_mapping = {
    'properties': {
        'timestamp': { 'type': 'date' },
    }
}

ESCONN.indices.put_mapping("TestObject", obj_mapping, [INDEX_NAME])

for i in range(0, 5):
    ESCONN.index(index=INDEX_NAME, doc_type="TestObject", body={
        'timestamp': datetime.now(),
    })

    print "Stored %d" % i
```

I'm trying to store a document with a field (called `timestamp`) containing the value of `datetime.now()`. Afterwards, I want to request all the documents where the value of this `timestamp` is within a certain range:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/datetime-test/try/_search" -d'
{
 "query": {
    "range": {
      "timestamp": {
         "gt" : "now-1h"
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

The search query comes back empty.

```
{
  "took" : 2,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 0,
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea why the search is coming back empty and what should I be doing to ensure that Elasticsearch is interpreting my `timestamp` field correctly so that my documents show up in a query that is searching for a datetime range?

I'm using the following versions:
 - Elasticsearch: 1.4.4
 - elasticsearch-py: 1.4.0

It is worth noting that `elasticsearch.yml` is currently empty.

[edit]

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/datetime-test/_mapping/TestObject?pretty'
{
  "datetime-test" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "TestObject" : {
        "properties" : {
          "timestamp" : {
            "type" : "date",
            "format" : "dateOptionalTime"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[/edit]

Comment: Check that your mapping has the field as a date type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be a UTC versus local time issue.

When I ran your code, and tried this, I got results:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
   "query": {
      "range": {
         "timestamp": {
            "gt": "now-12h"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

On the other hand, when I changed `'timestamp': datetime.now(),` to `'timestamp': datetime.utcnow(),`, your query worked.

For completeness, here's the full example I used:

Python code:

```
from datetime import datetime
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

INDEX_NAME = "test_index"

ESCONN = Elasticsearch()

if ESCONN.indices.exists(INDEX_NAME):
    ESCONN.indices.delete(index = INDEX_NAME, ignore=[400, 404])

ESCONN.indices.create(index=INDEX_NAME, ignore=400)

obj_mapping = {
    'properties': {
        'timestamp': { 'type': 'date' },
    }
}

ESCONN.indices.put_mapping("doc", obj_mapping, [INDEX_NAME])

for i in range(0, 5):
    ESCONN.index(index=INDEX_NAME, doc_type="doc", body={
        'timestamp': datetime.utcnow(),
    })

    print "Stored %d" % i
```

Sense code:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
   "query": {
      "range": {
         "timestamp": {
            "gt": "now-1h"
         }
      }
   }
}
...
{
   "took": 3,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 5,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "_AaKzzXLQuiLyBAjT9YDqA",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "timestamp": "2015-03-07T19:35:51.914612"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "rCSziknqTKWXfoY7hRJiIw",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "timestamp": "2015-03-07T19:35:51.919175"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "5yXtPWGATwe4n3kAVbwRfg",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "timestamp": "2015-03-07T19:35:51.909425"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "fwNb4iVVQFmPi9jo8PZxhA",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "timestamp": "2015-03-07T19:35:51.912478"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "PGHXxzvKRrakvJWMRtVQXQ",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "timestamp": "2015-03-07T19:35:51.916854"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: First of all thanks heaps for having a look at this Sloan. After looking at your code I realised my main mistake is most likely that my search query used the wrong API call. The path I used was `<index>/try/_search` and you used `<index>/_search`. If I used the one you used I get my results. Thanks for your help. Glad it was something rather simple.